# Newton's Law of Cooling (Prove of Uniqueness)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having a problem understanding a prove of uniqueness for the Newton's Law of Cooling:

So, the ODE it is as follows:

$u_t = \kappa (\bar{u} - u)$

In order to prove uniqueness we assume that there is another solution $\tilde{u}$ and we multiply both sides by an integrating factor $e^{\kappa t}$:

$e^{\kappa t} \tilde{u}_t$ + $\kappa e^{\kappa t} \tilde{u} = \kappa e^{\kappa t} \bar{u}$

But, I'm clueless on how to proceed with these.

The main idea is to prove that $u = \tilde{u}$.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your new equation should involve both $\tilde{u}$ and $u$; you should be trying to show that $\tilde{u}-u$ is constant, presumably by showing that its derivative vanishes everywhere.